# Thread Crossing in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have used two threads in my application(WindowsForms). The one thread for getting ThumbnailImages of clients and another thread for getting fullsize Images of Clients...its working but not properly... When i click thumbnail image button its giving thumbnail image properly after that i click that fullsize image button,It came as fullsize image and thumbnail images too... then return back to thumbnail image button it came as thumbnail images and Fullsize images also....

The two threads are crossing Thats why i didnt get proper output....

How can i Solve this Problem? Tell me the solution Of this...

Here is my Code....

```
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startlooping));
    th.Start();
}

void StartLooping()
{
    localconnection();

    for (int i = 0; i < Num_Picbox; i++)
    {
        clsImage pcimg = frmDisplay.Serviceobj.ConnectToPcAndGetImage(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), imgid);

        Image img = objConvertByteToStream.byteArrayToImage(pcimg.pcimage);

        if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString() == pcimg.IPadd && imgid == 0)
        {
            shapes[i].Image = img;
        }

        pcimg = null;
    }
}

private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pb= sender as PictureBox;

    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetImage));

    thread.Start();
}

void GetImage()
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    btnBack.Visible = true;

    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

    label1.Visible = true;
    pictureBox1.Height = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Height;
    pictureBox1.Width = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Width;

    btnGetConnectedPcs.Location = new Point(168, 616);

    btnGetImageFromSelectedPc.Location = new Point(352, 616);

    for (; ; )
    {
        count++;
        int imageid = 1;
        localconnection();

        string strIpaddress = listBox1.Items[Convert.ToInt32(pb.Name)].ToString();
        .........................
        .........................
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps some sort of synchronisation is in order?

Comment: how shall i solve this synchronization?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use CheckForIllegalCrossThreads and use Invoke on the controls you're using.

Comment: I am new to this thread concept...i couldnt understand... So can you give me some explanation or example in my code...

Comment: Sury, you should take a few minutes to read the documents everyone has taken the time to provide and take a swing at it yourself before asking people to write your code. Your experience at SO will be better for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), instead.  Don't ever use `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`; it's there for a reason.

It deals with "marshalling" (getting calls on one thread to switch to another thread for UI updating purposes).

Here's a good starter: http://bigballofmud.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/thread-marshalling-part-2-using-backgroundworker/

Also, you need to control the UI when the other threads are running.  Typically by disabling buttons/menus etc to prevent the user asking for more things like one is already running.

At the very least you should be using `Control.Invoke`.  When your thread has finished downloading images, it should call a method to display them.  That method should then check `this.InvokeRequired`, and if it is true, should call itself via `this.Invoke` or `this.BeginInvoke`.  This will effectively switch back to the main UI thread and avoid the errors you were probably seeing.

## Plz to send me the codez?

Okay, this time you can have a bit more, but you also need to master the skill of taking some directions then finding your own way.  If we help you with actual code for this problem you'll just come back when you get stuck next time.  We'd prefer to set you going like a wind-up toy than steer you the whole way like a remote-controlled car :)

### BackgroundWorker

I'm going to refer you to the [BackgroundWorker article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for this.

The BackgroundWorker is a component you drop on your form from the toolbox.  It's not a visual control like a textbox, instead it's more like a Timer or Tooltip.

Using it in it's simplest form means subscribing to the `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events, as described in the MSDN article.  When you want some downloading to happen, you need to do the following:

- Disable your UI (to prevent subsequent button presses).
- Set some sort of progress/working animation or message.
- Call `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync`, passing in an object containing parameters that tell it what to do (i.e. download large or small images).

The `DoWork` event in your case will be raised, and your method will be running in a different thread to your UI, so you are not allowed to update the UI at all in this method.  Write your DoWork method to download the images and set the `DoWorkEventArgs.Result` property to that collection of images once the download is complete.

When the `DoWork` method completes, the BackgroundWorker will fire the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, and the method you subscribed to it will be called.  This code will now automatically be running on the UI thread again, so you should do the following:

- Report on any errors in the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error` property (essentially this is any untrapped errors that occurred in the DoWork method.  Deal with them here so you can use the UI to inform the user of the problem).
- Create your controls to display the images contained in the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.`
- Hide any progress indicators.
- Re-enable your UI (preferably using a finally block so that any exceptions don't result in your UI being permanently and irretrievably locked).

Comment: i could nt get your point... Can you tell me that explanation on my code? or can you edit my code where should i change the code?

Comment: Plz to send me the codez? Okay, this time you can have a bit more (no code, mind you), but you also need to master the skill of taking some directions then finding your own way. If we help you with actual code for this problem you'll just come back when you get stuck next time. We'd prefer to set you going like a wind-up toy than steer you the whole way like a remote-controlled car :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a quick look at [Control.InvokeRequired()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx). That is likely to shed some light and give you a clear path to success.

Good luck.

Comment: well, sury, that link will take you directly to a page that will explain it to you in detail with example code. Probably more efficient that way, dontcha think? ;-)

Comment: And you will have absorbed the information regarding the whys and hows so you will have it next time you need it. fishes, teaching and all that....

Comment: still i confused in this thread!! can you edit my code in few lines?plz

Comment: no. because not only is it broken, it is not complete. I wouldn't have enough information to make an informed analysis unless i want to spend time trying to figure what you are trying to and what is happening in the code that is missing.  TIP: posting broken code is encouraged and accepted. posting _incomplete_ _broken_ code is a surefire way to get slight response. sorry but is true.